# Asp.net create webpage based on ID and link into SQL view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a few questions and they maybe stupidly simple so please be nice :).

I've just started playing with ASP.NET to create an intranet site for my workplace (Its a side project but really enjoying the coding side of it so want to expand my lacking skill set) and I will give you a quick overview so you can understand where I'm coming from..

I have a page in which displays one column from a database view and has a hyperlink with whatever output comes from the database so this can range from AA11 to ZZZZ or 1111 to 999Z etc, and I have it to link to Website~/TestBay/Details.aspx?id=***DATABASEOUTPUT*** example : Website~/TestBay/Details.aspx?id=***4F61***

So my question is, how do I create a dynamic page which having to create a page for EVERY possible combination that maybe output? Can I create a template that is triggered when clicked to create page based on the data output.

Code I'm using for the hyperlink below:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        id:
        <a href="Details.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>"><%# Eval("id") %></a>
        <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Which seems to work its just page it outputs too. If I cant create a dynamic page based on the ID given am I able to set a 'details' page and pass through the ID so I can put it into an SQL command?

Thank you very much in advanced
Jamie Barton

Comment: This is a bit broad for SO, you are really looking for a tutorial. Try this for starters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/stc0szde(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: so you want your details page to accept the `id` parameter, perform a query using it, then return the results of the query to the page?

Comment: I think so @markpsmith but this is the first time doing anything like this so its all new so pardon my 'rookieness'.

Comment: @BenRobinson Thanks I will have a look at it now.